# Call an interface function from an unknown derived class (multiple inheritance)

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an array of `Base*` objects. This holds a bunch of derived objects, some of which may implement an `Interface`.

```
struct Base {
    virtual void doNotCallThis() { cout << "nooo" << endl; }
};

struct Interface {
    virtual void doThis() = 0;
};

// Example derived class
struct Derived : Base, virtual Interface {
    virtual void doThis() { cout << "yes" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Base* b[1];
    b[0] = new Derived(); // Here would be a bunch of different derived classes
    ((Interface*)b[0])->doThis(); // Elsewhere, doThis() would be called for select array elements
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
nooo
```

I don't know the exact type of `b[i]` at run time, so I can't cast to `Derived` (it could be `Derived2`, `Derived3`, etc). I also can't use dynamic_cast if that's a solution. All I know is that, by the time I call `doThis()`, `b[i]` is a type that inherits from `Interface`. The way I attempted to call it above causes the wrong function to be called, eg. `Base::doNotCallThis()`.

How can I call it properly?

Comment: You cannot cast `b[0]` legally to `Interface*`, that's just undefined behavior.

Comment: I would have thought that the right thing is to introduce an intermediate base-class that inherits both `Base` and `Interface`, that all `Derived` classes can depend on - and then make `Base* b[1]` into that class.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I would do this but some `Derived` classes inherit from derivations of `Base`, which would cause them to derive from it twice.

Comment: So those classes would have to be re-defined to inherit from that new intermediate class!

Comment: @MatsPetersson Kind of confused if this is what you're saying: I have `Base`, `Base1 : Base`, `Base2 : Base`, etc. say 10 derivations. So for each of those used in conjunction with `Interface`, I'd have to define `JoinedBaseNumberX : BaseX, virtual Interface`? Then I wouldn't know which joined derivation to use either...

Comment: @idlackage You probably have a flaw in your inheritance design. For every derived class thoroughly ask yourself ***is it*** actually same as `Base`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am certain that they are not the same as `Base`. Design aside is there truly just no way to call a function of a parent that I know an object is the child of?

Comment: In  short, if you want to cast `Base` to `Interface`, you must inherits `Interface` from `Base`. In your code Base and Interface are un-related, direct casting results in UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing an answer with the risk of being downvoted:

If we start with::

```
struct Base()
{
   virtual void SomeFunc();
};

struct Interface
{
   virtual void doThis();
}
```

then to create a bunch of derived functions from Base that are also interfaces, I'd do something like this:

```
struct BaseInterface : public Base, public Interface
{
  // Nothing here - this is just combining Base and Interface 
};

struct Base1 : public BaseInterface
{
   ... add stuff that Base1 has that isn't in Base.
};

struct Derived: public Base1
{
  ... some more stuff that isn't in Base1 
}
```

And then we use it in Main like this:

```
int main() {
    BaseInterface* b[1];
    b[0] = new Derived(); // Here would be a bunch of different derived classes
    b[0])->doThis(); // Elsewhere, doThis() would be called for select array elements
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't exactly use this but it did help me realize that there is a fundamental design problem with the interface itself; I ended up just merging it directly into `Base` (as opposed to deriving from them both into a new base). Not sure how nicely this would work if I had more interfaces, or at least ones that were less compatible, but for this situation your answer solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As other people have pointed out, you would probably do best to find a way to refactor your design so that casting isn't necessary.

But putting that aside, I can explain what's going wrong and how to correctly cast.

The problem with `((Interface*)b[0])` is that since `Base` and `Interface` are unrelated the compiler has to do a blind reinterpretive cast. Practically speaking that means in this situation the resulting pointer doesn't actually line up with the `Interface` part of the object. If you were to try `static_cast<Interface*>(b[0])` you would find it doesn't compile - and that's a big hint that it's the wrong kind of cast to be making.

On the other hand, the compiler does know the relationship from `Base` to `Derived` and also from `Derived` to `Interface`. So as long as you know *for sure* that the object not only implements `Interface` but also is a `Derived` then you can do:

```
static_cast<Interface*>(static_cast<Derived*>(b[0]))->doThis();
```

However if your design has multiple different derived types which independently implement `Interface` then you might not be able to do that unless again you *absolutely* know what the derived type is at any time you go to make the call. - This is why refactoring it into a better class hierarchy is more desirable, since it's much less fragile and cumbersome to work with.

(As a side note, this issue points out why it's a great idea to never use raw/reintrepretive casts when moving up and down a class hierarchy. At least use `static_cast` since the can compiler better help you do it correctly.)

Comment: Great explanation, the silliness of what I was trying to accomplish makes a lot of sense now. I did end up refactoring my code by putting the code from `Interface` directly into `Base`--said interface should only be applied to `Base`-derived objects anyway.